# What does ""Files Changed" mean in a pull request webpage?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

In GitHub, after I create a pull request to merge a number of commits into master from the feature branch, I click the pull request, and saw:

> Tim  wants to merge 3 commits into master from feature

Below it , there are three tags:

> "Conversation 0"   "Commits 3"   "Files changed 33"

when I click "Files changed 33", I guess that it will show the output of `git diff` between a commit on the feature branch and a commit on the master branch. 
My questions are:

- which commit on the feature branch? The latest commit on the feature branch? So if I further push a new commit on the feature branch to GitHub, will the results shown on "Files changed 33" be updated?
- which commit on the master branch: the master branch's commit at which the feature branch was forked,  or to the latest commit on the master branch?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand this question. Your branch is "ahead" 3 commits of the branch in the remote repository, those 33 files are in those 3 commits. What is the question here?

Comment: Lasse is right. It is not comparing anything. It's just saying there are 3 commits as part of your pull request, and 33 files have changed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: when I click "Files changed 33", it will show the output of `git diff` between a commit on the feature branch and a commit on the master branch. My question is which commit on the master branch `git diff` compares the latest commit on the feature branch?

Comment: @Tim Why not just try it yourself? It is not that hard to create repository on GitHub and push some commits to it.

Answer (score 1):

The commits on your pull request are compared to the latest commit on the `master` branch. It wouldn't make much sense to compare them to the point at which the repo was forked, because many changes may have happened in between that may be in conflict with your changes. And if you tried to merge your changes without being aware of these conflicts bad things could happen :)

Actually, if you look closely, GitHub does something interesting. When you're looking at the "files changed" tab of your pull request, and someone happens to push a commit to `master`, you'll see a small warning on the page saying that "the page is out of date", and if you refresh it you'll see the new diff. GitHub automatically calculates the "files changed" every time someone pushes code into `master`.

Comment: In my experience GitHub compare merge base between `master` and pull request branch (not latest commit of `master` branch) with latest commit of pull request branch. And, IMHO, it make little sense to compare against latest commit of `master` branch, because accepting pull request will not remove any changes introduced in `master` after commit, on which pull request is based. And if merge can not be made clearly, then GitHub will just refuse to do automatic merge and you will have to resolve conflicts manually.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari  can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826650/error-could-not-apply-tried-it-in-proper-way-by-seeing-instructions-but-st?noredirect=1#comment74692370_43826650