# error: could not apply ---> tried it in proper way by seeing instructions but still errors for git squash

Tags: git, squash

I am new to git and I tried to squash my commits.

In my branch, it shows my 32 commits (John Smith), within that three commits of another two developers too (Prince Rolf and Harry).

For one commit a developer has amended.

Now if I try to squash all the commits I am getting an error:

error: could not apply ccdfa76... Add readme.md

I googled for the error, but was not able to find it.
I tried squashing by ten and then ten but that also throwing error.
Can you guys tell me how to swim it providing the error below?

**$ git rebase -i  aaaa**

```
pick 04dc4d0 play: wip sports
pick f255d38 play: sports
```

Comment: I see you have merge commits. Have you tried including the `-p` (`--preserve-merges`) switch as well when you attempt to rebase?

Comment: @J.Titus hey I got confused...it would be great if you tell me the set of commands I need to execute :(

Comment: Try to do the same thing you did before, but include `-p` as well since you have some merge commits in the list of commits you're trying to squash. So `$ git rebase -pi 1a3cc3`. I'm not 100% sure this will work since I haven't tried it myself..

Comment: @J.Titus I have one more question when I change pick to s can I change pick to s to any commits or I should not touch the first line....i should not miss any code when i do squash

Comment: Don't touch the first line. That's the commit all your other commits will be squashed into. EDIT: Or, change the first line to `reword` if you want to reword the commit message.

Comment: @J.Titus can you tell me the commit for edit

Comment: The rebase command does not change. Instead of `pick`, change the first line to `reword` to reword the commit message. You can follow the instructions Git prints out when you start the interactive rebase.

Comment: @J.Titus hey still it didn't work...are we doing something wrong ---> $ git rebase -pi 1a3cc30564690fbf72f80056bd6d7cfa166497e3
**Refusing to squash a merge: c0ad7755f58f1bef92d71b72b8e1397b9e07fdea**

Comment: Not sure at this point. Sorry :(

Comment: to get an idea about where all your branches are, do this: git log --oneline --graph --decoreate=short --all. Without knowing too much about what the situation is, I'd try to rebase your changes on your branch onto master (no squashing). Once you do that successfully, then squash.  Also, make sure you're remote master is in synch with the remote repository before you start anything.

Comment: @pixelbits hey thanks for your reply...I got so confused now...it would be great if you let me know set of commands I need to execute :(

Comment: can you post a picture of: git log --oneline --graph --decorate=short --all

Comment: @pixelbits do you want from my local branch or master branch...I thought my git log will help  you guys

Comment: it doesn't matter which branch you do it on.  The "--all" switch will show all branches.

Comment: @pixelbits hey I have updated git log graph in my question you can see it in my fiddle also here https://jsfiddle.net/j2yzdam2/

Comment: I would just re-base onto origin/master interactively. i.e. git rebase -i origin/master.   By the way... where is local master?

Comment: @pixelbits hello I didn't understand...can you tell me what command do I need to execute?? and in which branch??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt to `rebase` with `squash` **has not failed**. What you see not an error.

Your rebase operation has been **paused**.

Read carefully the message:

> **When** you have **resolved** this problem, run **"git rebase --continue"**.
>   **If you prefer** to skip this patch, run **"git rebase --skip" instead.**
>   To check out the original branch and **stop rebasing**, run **"git rebase --abort"**.
>   Could not apply ccdfa7670a8eb780954edd1383e3378ef43292ac... Add readme.md

Look at the commands suggested. `rebase / continue`, `rebase / skip`, `rebase 
/ abort`. This essentially tells you that the rebase is still ongoing. It is paused. You can ignore the problem and skip, you can do something and continue, or you can abort (and rollback) the rebase completely.

Ok. So we know what's the situation. Now, let's check WHY.
If you read the message, you know it's "cannot apply **ccdfa(..)**".

You could not check the status, index, etc, to see what's up, but you has not shown them. So, for now let's use what you gave us already.

If to read things really carefully, we can notice this note in the git log:

> commit **c0ad7755f58f1bef92d71b72b8e1397b9e07fdea**
>   **Merge: ccdfa76 b1ba9e4**
>   Author: Prince Rolf 
>   Date:   Tue March 2 19:07:32 2017 -0500
>
> Merge branch 'sports-module' of gitlab.cell.com:grp-imco-products/im-lap-sports into sports-module
>
> **# Conflicts:
>
>     #   README.md**

Look at the shouting "CONFLICTS". It's not a thing you often see in the commit message. That's commit `c0ad77(..)` (not the one we have problem with), but as you can see in its headers, this is a merge of the commit `ccdfa76` (the one we have problem with) and `b1ba9e4` (unknown so far).

Now look at the tree of commits, let's look for those commit IDs.

> * 04dc4d0 play: wip sports
>   *   **c0ad775 Merge branch** 'sports-module' of gitlab.paper.com:chain/catch-sports into sports-module
>   |\
>   | * **b1ba9e4** play: sports
>   | * a2464b1 adding sports files
>   | * 1a3cc30 play: wip sports
>   * **ccdfa76** (origin/master) **Add readme.md**

Hey, all of them happen to be at the very start of the history (bottom). Great. It will simplify looking at them.

That `b1ba9e4` sits on top of `a2464b1` which in turn sits on top of `1a3cc30` - and that's the rebase root you wrote in your rebase command.

`c0ad775` is indeed a merge between the part that contains rebase-root and the `ccdfa76` (problematic one) which is 'aside' the rest.

Now, let's look at the start of your rebase command:

```
git rebase -i 1a3cc30
pick ccdfa76 Add readme.md
squash a2464b1 adding sports files
squash b1ba9e4 play: sports
squash 04dc4d0 play: wip sports
squash f255d38 play: sports
```

Detailed command are not important right now. What's important is the **effective sequence of commits** that you requested:

```
0: 1a3cc30     \ (rebase root)
1: ccdfa76  ---:----- (problematic one)
2: a2464b1     |
3: b1ba9e4     /
-:(c0ad775)      (merge, not mentioned in rebase plan, so not requested)
4: 04dc4d0  ...
5: f255d38  ...
```

Looking at the commit tree, you try to inject the `ccdfa76` (left side of tree) into the middle of right side of tree. Remember that the `c0ad775 merge` glued these two tree parts together and it had a **conflict** at 'readme' file. Remember that `ccdfa76` message says `adding readme file`.

So now, apparently, the rebase has halted when trying to apply `ccdfa76` onto `1a3cc30` with **the same conflict** at 'readme' file.

Apparently, `ccdfa76` tries to add a `readme` file, but `1a3cc30` already has a readme file. Hence conflict.

That's my guess. Now let's get to the console.

Now start over, cleanup everything.
Do your rebase command with the same plan as before (pick/s/s/s/s/s.../s).
Wait until `cannot apply ccdfa(..)` shows up.
Remember that rebase is not faulted - it is paused so you can fix it and continue.
Now run `git status` and see what it says.

It should say something like:

```
git status
# On branch FOOBAR
# You have unmerged paths.
#   (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add ..." to mark resolution)
#
# both added:      readme.md
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Alright, so there's really conflict at this readme file. Now you can fix it. Open that file, find markers like

```
bum
<<<<<
bleh
=====
blah
>>>>>
whooo
```

This are merge conflicts markers. I wont explain how they work. Read about it online, or just use a merge tool of sorts (like i.e. KDiff3 or WinMerge or whatever).

The most important point is: **edit the file and make sure it looks like you want it to look**. When you end editing, there should be no markers inside.

When you finish fixing the conflict, run this to tell git that the conflicts in this file were all fixed:

```
git add readme.md
```

Yes. That's just plain old `add`. After that, use the command that was suggested in the "error message":

```
git rebase --continue
```

and the rebase will take your fixed file, and ..continue. Most probably, it will then run to the end.

Or will hit into another conflict in the same or another file, which you will need to fix in a similar way, and continue, and so on.

Be careful - whenever `rebase` pauses, there may be **many** files under conflict. Git Status will show them all. Also, when fixing conflicts, remember that there may be many conflicts in a single file (many markers in various parts of the file).

Summing up, commandline activity looks like this:

```
> git rebase -i 1a3cc30
(...)
error: cannot apply (..)

> git status
(....)
#aha! I see a conflict at "readme.md"
(...)

> vim readme.md            #edit, fix, save
> git add readme.md        # tell Git that file is OK now
> git rebase --continue    # tell git to get back to work

# now either it's ok, or another conflict - rinse and repeat until finished
```

Comment: hello, I followed your steps now when i do git status it shows **$ git status
On branch swim-kick
Your branch and 'origin/swim-kick' have diverged,
and have 1 and 32 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean**

Comment: and then git log it shows two commits **$ git log
commit 3bcde19ce171705c3590e2bdcdf3e3f8d5e7496a
Author: Harry <tharry@sports.com>
Date:   Tue May 2 09:26:41 2017 -0500

    play: SPORTS


commit 1a3cc30564690fbf72f80056bd6d7cfa166497e3
Author: John Smith <John.Smith@sports.com>
Date:   Tue March 2 09:04:11 2017 -0500

    play: wip sports**

Comment: after I did git rebase it should so only one commit right?? if it should one commit I would have executed this comment  **git push origin [swim-kick] -f
**  now how should I need to proceed??

Comment: @texirv: In general, 'diverged' means that your **local** "swim-kick" and **remote** "swim-kick" branches differ in a non-linear way. That is normal after rebase, since rebase rewrites the history. After you did the rebase locally, the remote repo was not updated yet. So, if you finished the rebase, then you'd have commits "A->B" but on the remote repo would be still old "A->C-D-F-G...". That's why the message say: 1 and 32. Your local is 1 after "A", remote is 32 after "A".

Comment: can I execute this command now **git push origin [swim-kick] -f**

Comment: @texirv: regarding second question: Assuming you work as JohnSmith and that the date on your machine is correct (now = 7th or 8th may) - if you now see `3bcde19ce171705c3590e2bdcdf3e3f8d5e7496a` by Harry - this is **very strange**. You posted the log and we saw no such commit by Harry. However, this new Harry's commit is from May-2nd and the log you posted said only about commits from March. I guess that when you start working on this rebase **few days ago**, you cloned/fetched/pulled from the repo and ... since then you never cared to update. And Harry commited a new thing in the meantime.

Comment: hello it was all March by mistake I typed May...can I execute this command now git push origin [swim-kick] -f

Comment: @texirv: the third question - `push` with `-f` - You have to be aware that `push --force` will overwrite the branch, maybe partially, maybe completely. In your case, you squashed all commits, so probably it will be complete overwrite. You should ensure that the rebase you just did **really includes the new changes that Harry has recently posted**. If you don't do that, then after `push -f` his changes may fall out of the history tree and may effectively be lost. Check his commit, compare your rebased version. Ensure that rebased version contains his changes, only then push.

Comment: @texirv: if it was a typo and if that commit was from March,2nd - then why wasn't it visible in the log you provided earlier? If it were on this branch, it should be visible back then. My advise - proceed with caution, check what that commit contained, make sure that contents of this commit were included in the rebase OR that you can ignore it (i.e. because it was later overwritten with other things, etc), and if anything's wrong, re-do the rebase properly with respect of that commit. Then push -f and done. Just remember to notify ASAP Harry&all that they have to sync harder after push+force.

Comment: (asap - because the later they notice that push+force and rewrite of the history the worse collisions they will get when they finally sync)

Comment: but still why I am seeing two cmmits when I do git log...the main reason we did squash was to combine all the commits into single commit right??

Comment: can you explain to me this line..I am not getting it ----> Looking at the commit tree, you try to inject the ccdfa76 (left side of tree) into the middle of right side of tree.

Comment: @texirv: re 2 commits: yes, the rebase you did (pick/s/s/s/s../s) creates one large commit out of all commits you list in the "plan". Note that the "rebase root" is NOT SHOWN on the plan. The rebase root stays unchanged. So, after that you are left with unchanged rebase root and a huge joint commit sitting on top of the rebase base = 2 commits.

Comment: @texirv: re 'explain inject': look at the beginning of the log tree: there is a c0ad775 and it has two lines going to it. First (left) line is `c0ad775 <- ccdfa76` and second (right) is `c0ad775 <- b1ba9e4 <- a2464b1 <-  1a3cc30`. The c0ad775 joins them and forms a tree. This is what I mean by left and right side. Your rebase picks commits from these two sides and forms a linear plan:  `pick: ccdfa76, squash: a2464b1, squash: b1ba9e4 (..)`. Note the rebase root is there, just not mentioned. In fact, the plan is: `root: 1a3cc30, pick: ccdfa76, squash: a2464b1, squash: b1ba9e4 (..)`

Comment: this means, that rebase will try to create this commit hierarchy:  `(..) <-
 b1ba9e4 <- a2464b1 <- ccdfa76 <- 1a3cc30` and of course squash them, but the order is important: look how `ccdfa76` was inserted in between original right-side `b1ba9e4 <- a2464b1 <- (ccdfa76) <- 1a3cc30`. This is what I meant by "injecting". "Inserting in between" maybe would be better phrase.

Comment: @quez hello its so confusing can you tell us a, b, c for commits or 1, 2,3...so it will be easy to understand :(

Comment: @texirv: No I can't.  I can't, because you have edited the question, and it now uses  "aa" "bbb" "ccc" names for commits, but **the smaller commit tree that you included now IS NOT THE SAME as it was before**. Right now you took a part around `162e698 swim: width issue` (this is the TOP of the tree, the newest part) whereas what you need to focus on is the part around `c0ad775 merge` (which is at the BOTTOM, the OLDEST part of the history)

Comment: @texirv: I rolled back the previous version of your question. Please focus on GIT LOG GRAPH part, scroll it down to the bottom and look at **c0ad775 Merge branch 'sports-module' of** and all commits below that, then read `re 'explain inject'` again. All I talk about in `re 'explain inject'` is in the GIT LOG GRAPH at the bottom, at **c0ad775 Merge branch** itself and 4 commits directly below it. If you want to change that to A-B-C-D notation, please pick THAT part of the graph.